# Using a Form in a separate Project

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

Has anyone successfully been able to use a form created in one project in another with VS2015?

I have created many forms that I usually need to include in most of my projects, however whenever I try to add them to the new project I can never seem to get them to work.

I would like to add them to a separate project, with their code and designer/image references etc, but I have only been successful in adding the form with code no resources or designer.

Instead I am currently having to manually re-create the same form in a new project and copy and paste and reset all the controls and labels and what not in the newer solution.

In the past I used to do it like this guy did: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPBMoibAmU0 But it doesn't seem to work with VS2015?

Surely there's a simple way to do this? My way works but it's very time consuming and I think unnecessary.

So what I used to do in the past: Copy the form1.Designer.cs, form1.cs into the new solutions directory, then in the new solution, right-click the project properties, add existing file and browse and select the two files and click OK.

Comment: _"Has anyone successfully been able to use a form created in one project in another with VS2015"_ -- yes. It happens all the time. And yes, it's very simple. If you need help with your own attempt, you need to provide details. Include a good [mcve] showing clearly what you tried, and explain in detail what happens, and how that's different from what you want to happen.

Comment: @PeterDuniho thanks for the reply, I'm sorry I thought it was a pretty straight forward question, I added a link to a Youtube video of how a guy did it, I also stated I used that same method in the past, I thought that was a good enough example? I don't see why you down voted me? Its a legitimate accurate question. I added How i used to do it in the past for you.

Comment: Please read [ask] to understand better how you can present your question in a clear, answerable way. Be sure you read the articles, links to which are provided at the bottom of that page.

Comment: Everything I have found here hasn't worked for me as a solution it is why I asked the question, if you have a solution please by all means give me one. The answer here is what i used to do: stackoverflow.com/questions/863582/… but it doesn't seem to keep the designers visual side its all reset with no controls like a default form, and it does not add the resources, I want to add the form, not the project, adding an existing project is easy but i just want the form.

Comment: Is Add as Link not there in 2015 anymore?   It is still there in 2013.    Just like you were going to add to a project and Existing Item....  browse to the other project and notice the down arrow by the Add button.  Click that arrow and then choose Add as Link.  - I think that is what you are referring to.    BTW - I stopped using that feature around 2008, never turned out as expected - but it did preserve very compilcated form code and allow reuse of the form.  My quick google search makes me wonder if this is a project type deprecation in vs2015 and not all project types are affected.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, people re-use code all the time, this question is coming from a fundamental misunderstanding about how code and projects work. Code intended to be shared should be created in a shared project or shared/distributed library.

Using a distributed library:

- Create a class library (.dll)
- Add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`
- Define any code, forms, resources that are intended to be re-used here.
- Compile library and retrieve `.dll` file.
- Copy `.dll` file into your new project and add a reference to it.
- Use the form.

This is essentially how the `nuget` package manager works except it handles managing the physical `.dll` files and adding of references automatically. If you will be the only consumer of this and you don't intend to check your source code into a source control server (git, tfs, svn, etc) then you could also store this dll only in a single location (your documents folder, etc) so updating it is easier.

If you want to be able to make changes to the original source code in all the projects that use the form, you can instead add the original shared lib project to your new VS solution by right clicking on your solution, clicking add existing project, and navigating to the `csproj` file of your library project.

Comment: Very interesting, cheers for the info @caesay

Answer (score -1):

Wow I finally worked it out,

To add a existing form of another project to current:

1. Right-click the Project Properties in Solution Explorer.
2. Click "Add".
3. Click "Existing Item".
4. Browse only for the "Form1.cs" and select it, Click "OK".
5. Right click the added "Form1.cs" and select "View Code".
6. Look at top for "namespace", highlight the actual namespace eg: "namespace Form1", so highlight "Form1".
7. Right-click highlighted namespace and select "Rename...".
8. A box appears, tick "Include Comments", "Include Strings", then type the new name in(with still the Rename box visible) and Click "OK".
9. Now just add the resource files to the current project.

Comment: This seems wrong - I wouls have expected "link" ref like in previous versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: The above is a very poor way to "share" code from one project to another. By using "Add", Visual Studio will simply copy the .cs file from one project to the other. You might as well just select the whole thing and copy/paste. If you find a bug in the file or want to add features later, you have to do it in both places. Only slightly better would be to use "Add Link", which references the original .cs file in the new project. But this still requires the file to be compiled in each project. The best way to share code is via DLL, per the other posted answer (and every other related one).